# What is this furry, long-limbed, presumably tree-dwelling creature?

Tags: species-identification, zoology

Can anyone identify the species below? I believe the picture was taken at the Museum Of Zoology in Cambridge so maybe someone cleverer than me could narrow it down using [their collections search](https://www.museum.zoo.cam.ac.uk/collection/online).

[image]

Of the species I know, it looks most like a tarsier to me. Is there any relation?

Comment: It does look somewhat like a Tarsier. I looked a second on the wikipedia and the closest thing I could find was the [Tarsius fuscus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarsius_fuscus). I don't believe this is what you're looking for, but if it helps you in anyway to get to the goal of identifying it, I thought I would just leave this comment.

Comment: @Eff Thanks! The limbs look a lot more similar to tarsius fuscus. Looking at their collection, they only have one species from the tarsius genus, tarsius tarsier, which does not look like it matches the photo above. If that's correct, I wonder why it looks so different? Bad taxidermy?

Comment: Yeah it was the limbs that looked alike... But I really can't tell. I'm not the one to ask for these questions. I really don't have much expertise on phylogeny. I just thought that a very slight chance of helping was better than none, so I posted the comment. I upvoted question. Hope you get help!

Comment: It looks a lot more like a loris to me. There are 10 loris species. Not sure which one this is.

Comment: I just looked at the museum list for loris and tarsier. I think the one closest fitting is probably the [Red Slender Loris (*Loris tardigradus*)](http://www.edgeofexistence.org/species/red-slender-loris/).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a taxidermic specimen of a **gray slender loris** (Loris lydekkerianus), but it does look pale in color. The lack of color distinction in the fur may be because it is a non-living specimen. The links below may be helpful with more detail.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_slender_loris

https://www.shaldonwildlifetrust.org.uk/page/grey-slender-loris.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yU3n0BlUP0A

Comment: thank you! if it's a loris then according to their collection it's either a red slender loris or a Bengal slow loris. Both specimens are hundreds of years old, might the fur discolour in that time?

Comment: @Michael If you look at their collection, there is only one mounted loris skin. All the Nycticebus cougang specimens are wet (in fixative) or bones. So, if it's a loris and it's listed in their collection, it's a red slender loris.